# Using delegate to fire in a specific order?

Tags: jquery, delegates

What I'm trying to do is set it up so that when a link is clicked, an alert is fired. Is it possible to define which alert is fired first?

```
$("#container").delegate("a.link", "click", function(){                    
    alert("This was message #1");
});

$("#container").delegate("a.link", "click", function(){                    
    alert("This was message #2");
});
```

Comment: They will naturally fire in the same order in which the handlers are attached. Do you want a mechanism for firing in some order other than the natural order?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware it fires in the natural order. I'm trying to programmatically have them fire in an order that I specify.

Comment: In that case, how do you wish to specify the order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach which I use in code would be to set a second event-type for the second event listener:

```
$("#container").delegate("a.link", "click", function(){                    
    alert("This was message #1");
    $(this).trigger("click-event-2");
});

$("#container").delegate("a.link", "click-event-2", function(){                    
    alert("This was message #2");
});
```

Also worth mentioning is that [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) was surpassed by [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$("#container").on("click","a.link", function(){                    
    alert("This was message #1");
    $(this).trigger("click-event-2");
});

$("#container").on("click-event-2","a.link", function(){                    
    alert("This was message #2");
});
```

Comment: Yes, we should all be using `.on()`, but it's important to make sure the arguments are at least in the right order. You have to do more than substitute `.on` for `.delegate`.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot +1 It has been a while since I used .delegate :) Thanks for the catch.